# Why is (form.$error && form.$submitted) true on start?

Tags: ios, angularjs, forms, ionic-framework, cross-platform

This is the video of the bug http://youtu.be/siOfUluPraA
and below is my code.

It seems that 
ng-show=true for a split second

signinForm.$submitted = true for a split second

Login.html

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <div><h4>LOGIN TO YOUR ACCOUNT</h4></div>
    </div>

    <form name="signinForm" novalidate>
      <div class="list login">

        <!-- input username -->
        <label  class="item item-input item-top" 
            ng-class="{'form-has-error' : signinForm.username.$invalid && signinForm.username.$submitted}">
            <img src="./img/profile6.png" class= "image-thumb" alt="">
            <input  type="text" 
                    name="username" 
                    ng-model="user.username" 
                    ng-minlength="5"
                    required placeholder="Name or National Id">
        </label>
        <!-- validation username -->
        <div  class="form-errors"
              ng-show="signinForm.username.$error && signinForm.$submitted" 
              ng-messages="signinForm.username.$error" 
              ng-messages-include="templates/formerrors/form-errors-username.html">  
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

form-errors-username.html

```
<div class="form-error" ng-message="required">This field is required.</div>
<div class="form-error" ng-message="minlength">This field is must be at least 5 characters.</div>
```

config.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider

 .state('signin', {
    url: '/sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'SignInCtrl'
 });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');
});
```

What is the best practice?
Thanks in advance!

***** UPDATE *****

> I used ng-if="signinForm.$submitted"
>
> instead of ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML template is briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form, while your application is loading.

You can try to use [ngCloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to avoid the flicker effect.

`<div ng-show="form.$submitted" ng-cloak>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it, I used

ng-if="signinForm.$submitted"

instead of ng-show.